# Stored proc not returning rows - need some debugging tips

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc, with joins like so:

```
FROM    Salesforce_Pervasive.dbo.Account a
INNER JOIN  Salesforce_Pervasive.dbo.Contact c
    ON  a.Id = c.AccountId
INNER JOIN  Online_Security.dbo.Main_Security_table m
    ON  c.Id = m.Salesforce_Contact_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Website_Interactive.dbo.Extended_User_Object euo
    ON  m.Web_ID = euo.Web_ID       
WHERE   c.Id = @salesforce_id
```

I don't get any rows returned for a certain user (where I provide an ID). What would be some "leads" to investigate why this would be such?

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you run this not in a stored proc and you put in an id, do you get records?

Comment: I assume you've looked in the DB and there is data for that user? Remove the second inner join and try it again.

Comment: keep in mind, store procedures may return more than one resultset. look if no selects are performed before your one

Comment: I am going to try that and see. So far I ran each select query (broke it down) individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the stored procedure in SSMS with "Actual Execution Plan" turned on.

Mouse over the arrows showing actual row counts. See where they become zero.